# impresspages Main Home URL ipHomeUrl( )

Tags: php, function, url, impresspages

i try to get the main url of my web site by using function of

> ipHomeUrl();

The issue is this function bring also the path of languages even it was left , function bring auto the current languages path

is like that :

```
http://localhost/wesitename/fr/
```

what i want is get only :

```
http://localhost/wesitename/
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Maybe there are other functions that can help you much better?

Comment: i want make a link to admin page and webmail, So with ipHomeUrl can't going, Result will be http://localhost/wesitename/fr/admin/ ..... error. so what is the solution fo this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an URL to the website root, you can use:

```
ipConfig()->baseUrl()
```

It should work in a more correct way than cached URL

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution , this function will be useful for add link of admin page .

```
$baseUrl = ipStorage()->get('Ip', 'cachedBaseUrl');

echo ('<div class="AdminSide" > <a href="'.$baseUrl.'admin/">Admin Page</a>  |  <a href="'.$baseUrl.'webmail/"> WebMail</a></div>');
```

Comment: References : https://www.impresspages.org/docs/storage and https://www.impresspages.org/docs/class-ip-storage